# getCipherSuite() returns SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL

Tags: java, android, ssl, bouncycastle

I'm trying to make an https server on Android with a programmatically generated self signed certificate. I feel like I'm pretty close but I still can't connect to the https server. When I attempt to connect to the server with openssl I get the following:

```
openssl s_client -connect 192.168.1.97:8888
CONNECTED(00000003)
2895:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-50/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:602:
```

The code is the following:

```
public class HttpsHello {
    private static String domainName = "localhost";

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    public static void test(String[] args) {

        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);
            KeyPair KPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            X509V3CertificateGenerator v3CertGen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();

            int ran = new SecureRandom().nextInt();
            if (ran < 0) ran = ran * -1;

            BigInteger serialNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(ran);

            v3CertGen.setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
            v3CertGen.setIssuerDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));
            v3CertGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
            v3CertGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10)));
            v3CertGen.setSubjectDN(new X509Principal("CN=" + domainName + ", OU=None, O=None L=None, C=None"));


            v3CertGen.setPublicKey(KPair.getPublic());
            //   v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSAEncryption");

            v3CertGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");

            X509Certificate pkcert = v3CertGen.generateX509Certificate(KPair.getPrivate());
            //    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/testCert.cert");
            //  fos.write(pkcert.getEncoded());
            // fos.close();

            ByteArrayInputStream cert = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcert.getEncoded());

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(null);
            ks.setCertificateEntry("localhost", pkcert);

            // ks.load(cert,null);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf =
                    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
            kmf.init(ks, null);

            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();

            SSLServerSocket s
                    = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888);
            s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            //  s.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5"});
            //  s.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[]{"SHA1WithRSAEncryption"});
            System.out.println("Server started:");
            printServerSocketInfo(s);
            // Listening to the port
            SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            printSocketInfo(c);
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(c.getOutputStream()));
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            String m = r.readLine();
            w.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            w.newLine();
            w.write("Content-Type: text/html");
            w.newLine();
            w.newLine();
            w.write("<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>");
            w.newLine();
            w.flush();
            w.close();
            r.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Remote address = "
                + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Remote port = " + s.getPort());
        System.out.println("   Local socket address = "
                + s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local address = "
                + s.getLocalAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local port = " + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
                + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        SSLSession ss = s.getSession();
        System.out.println("   Cipher suite = " + ss.getCipherSuite());
        System.out.println("   Protocol = " + ss.getProtocol());
    }

    private static void printServerSocketInfo(SSLServerSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Server socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Socker address = "
                + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Socker port = "
                + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
                + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Want client authentication = "
                + s.getWantClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Use client mode = "
                + s.getUseClientMode());
    }
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT: I looked at two keytool generated keystores, one which worked and one that didn't. The one keystore which works has an entry in there for a PrivateKeyEntry where as the one which doesn't work has a trustedCertEntry. I then changed this code to print out the entry for the "localhost" alias and below is what I got, I'm guessing the issue is that it is a Trusted certificate entry and not a private key entry. How do I change that?

Trusted certificate entry:
    [0]         Version: 3
    SerialNumber: 752445443
    IssuerDN: CN=localhost,OU=None,O=None L,C=None
    Start Date: Mon May 26 09:17:01 CDT 2014
    Final Date: Sat Jun 22 09:17:01 CDT 2024
    SubjectDN: CN=localhost,OU=None,O=None L,C=None
    Public Key: RSA Public Key
    modulus: b75870cd29db79f8c015d440a27cc1e81c9dd829268efa2ce48efc596b33e9c60e1d1621e10aba34472b6f7890b16392db021c0358e665b1bf58a426fbc47e7c135da583e4cd6bb9c69668ee4ff1e05b1de8e7f5fb5604044a1087ac0181ba09f61ab5345d9be5d930889b7c328329d0d18cf53f4c5af6bff1f0e488744ea1fb
    public exponent: 10001
    Signature Algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
    Signature: 83df0e761e9df2e61d5354ca58379975e0d97fcd
    5201f8904b695d7bdbe08c5dfdfb8bcd6447657c
    19740797a66314b2547a45985166c11ebadc16c6
    c24b8e1d3c5de83ec1ac2c1c1092c3d06ed33408
    4cf2811c5f9dba8a9d3ef0dcb8fef760e4d1d704
    8fbb60eaa83eec23426fb9d8589e859a21a5ecce
    951901f8e16ab6cd

Comment: Where did `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` come from?

Comment: `"CN=" + domainName` is not quite right. Placing a DNS name in the `CommonName` is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/B Forums. You can still use it - just place a friendly name like "Internet Widgets". Place the DNS names in the `SubjectAltNames`.

Comment: The ssl null line comes from this line in the code `        System.out.println("   Cipher suite = " + ss.getCipherSuite());`

Comment: Ah, OK. That looks like a consequence of the failed handshake; and not the cipher suite that was being used in the negotiation. Can you provide an external URL to the server? Are you *CERTAIN* there's an SSL/TLS server listening at 8888?

Comment: There is a server, I've tried with curl and it fails on the handshake. This is running on an Android phone but I'll see if I can forward some ports to it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```
            s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites());
```

Remove this line. It is enabling the anonymous cipher suites, which are used when the server can't find its private key, which is the underlying problem here.

Comment: If I do that then I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Could not find any key store entries to support the enabled cipher suites.` on the `s.accept()` line.

Comment: Then there's some thing wrong with your key generation. Can't see it offhand but I would compare it with what happens if you generate a key via the keytool. In fact I don't understand why you're *not* using the keytool. Nobody will trust the certificate you're generating here.

Comment: This is for use internally by an android app, I kind of wanted each user to have their own cert. I am open to using a keytool generated one but I had trouble with that as well, I think I was getting a wrong keystore version error even though I was using the bouncy castle version everyone claimed works.

Comment: Well it's not going to work unless you sign the client cert by an issuer that the server trusts.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Why do I need a client cert? I just want to have a simple browser and that same app the browser is part of will have its own https server. This whole question here is only about the https server.

Comment: In that case why do you think you need SSL certificates at all? or SSL? If the application is just browsing to itself it all seems completely pointless.

Comment: Well I'm actually implementing a proxy but I figured I should start with a https server and go from there. For a proxy I need both ssl and non ssl.

Comment: I think I found something wrong with the cert. The entry is a trusted certificate entry instead of a private key entry. Look at my last edit of the main post. Thanks.

Comment: So you imported it into the keystore with a different alias than you used to generate the private key. I still don't understand why you're not just using the `keytool` instead of this smorgasbord.

Answer (score 0):

The handshake failure usually means there's no shared cipher suite:

```
2895:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

`SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL` looks like its both `eNULL` and `aNULL`. Did BouncyCastle *not* load any ciphers?

Below is the code I use for a hardened `SSLSocketFactoryEx`. It only provides TLS (`getInstance("TLS")`will still return a SSLv3 socket), and it only provides approved cipher suites (approved by me). Its not enough to provide approved ciphers - the list must intersect with what's available else there's an exception. There are a few fallback cipher suites to ensure a shared cipher suite between old servers like those provided by Microsoft.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

class SSLSocketFactoryEx extends SSLSocketFactory
{
    public SSLSocketFactoryEx() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(null,null,null);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(km, tm, random);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        initSSLSocketFactoryEx(ctx);
    }

    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites()
    {
        return m_ciphers;
    }

    public String[] getDefaultProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public String[] getSupportedProtocols()
    {
        return m_protocols;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException
    {
        SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);

        ss.setEnabledProtocols(m_protocols);
        ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(m_ciphers);

        return ss;
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(KeyManager[] km, TrustManager[] tm, SecureRandom random)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        m_ctx.init(km, tm, random);

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    private void initSSLSocketFactoryEx(SSLContext ctx)
    throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
    {
        m_ctx = ctx;

        m_protocols = GetProtocolList();
        m_ciphers = GetCipherList();
    }

    protected String[] GetProtocolList()
    {
        String[] preferredProtocols = { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.3" };
        String[] availableProtocols = null;

        SSLSocket socket = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket();

            availableProtocols = socket.getSupportedProtocols();
            Arrays.sort(availableProtocols);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[]{ "TLSv1" };
        }
        finally
        {
            if(socket != null)
                socket.close();
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredProtocols.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableProtocols, preferredProtocols[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredProtocols[i]);
        }

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    protected String[] GetCipherList()
    {
        String[] preferredCiphers = {

            // *_CHACHA20_POLY1305 are 3x to 4x faster than existing cipher suites.
            //   http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/04/speeding-up-and-strengthening-https.html
            // Use them if available. Normative names can be found at (TLS spec depends on IPSec spec):
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-nir-ipsecme-chacha20-poly1305-01
            //   http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-mavrogiannopoulos-chacha-tls-02
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_SHA",

            // Done with bleeding edge, back to TLS v1.2 and below
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",

            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",

            // TLS v1.0 (with some SSLv3 interop)
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",

            "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",
            "SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA",

            // RSA key transport sucks, but they are needed as a fallback.
            // For example, microsoft.com fails under all versions of TLS
            // if they are not included. If only TLS 1.0 is available at
            // the client, then google.com will fail too. TLS v1.3 is
            // trying to deprecate them, so it will be interesteng to see
            // what happens.
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
            "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
        };

        String[] availableCiphers = null;

        try
        {
            SSLSocketFactory factory = m_ctx.getSocketFactory();
            availableCiphers = factory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
            Arrays.sort(availableCiphers);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return new String[] {
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
                "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA",
                "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
            };
        }

        List<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < preferredCiphers.length; i++)
        {
            int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(availableCiphers, preferredCiphers[i]);
            if(idx >= 0)
                aa.add(preferredCiphers[i]);
        }

        aa.add("TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV");

        return aa.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    private SSLContext m_ctx;

    private String[] m_ciphers;
    private String[] m_protocols;
}
```

Comment: Yuor code leaks an SSL socket, and as he's already stated in comments to another answer that using all the enabled protocols still causes the problem, restricting them further can't possibly solve it.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I dont know anything about the other problem (he needs to explicitly state it here). The handshake alert indicates there are *NO* share cuipher suites. Hence the reason he was provided code to set the cipher suites based on what's available.

Comment: He is already doing that here: `s.setEnabledCipherSuites(s.getSupportedCipherSuites())`. Which in fact is a big part of the problem.